# jsrender object iteration changing order

Tags: javascript, templates, jsrender

I'm using jsrender to render my templates. I have an object which I am passing in, for the benefit of this questions it looks like (simplified):

```
var obj = { 'BETA', 'DEV', 'QA', 'UAT' }
```

[image]

I pass this into a simple template:

```
$.templates("environment_tabs",
                    '<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">' +
                        "{{props}}"+
                            '<li class="nav-item">' +
                                '<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{>key}}" role="tab">{{>key}}</a>' +
                            '</li>' +
                        "{{/props }}" + 
                   '</ul>' )
```

The template renders these values ok but it has changed the order from BETA, DEV, QA, UAT to QA, BETA, UAT, DEV

[image]

Comment: Object's keys are not ordered. Order in which they are fetched is not guaranteed by the spec.

Comment: Thanks. How do I ensure order then? Transfer to another container?

Comment: If the order is important then either use array or specify the order somewhere.